# Incorrect Histogram from CIAreaHistogram / CIHistogramDisplayFilter

Tags: macos, cocoa, image-processing, core-image, cifilter

I have a function that generates a CIImage* of a histogram, given a CGImageRef being passed in to the routine.

I get a histogram image back but the left side of the histogram appears to be compressed and the right side appears to be stretched out. I am wondering if I need to apply a CTM or should the code just return the proper image.

Here is the function:

```
- (CIImage*)histogramFromCGImage:(CGImageRef)image
{
    CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image];

    CIVector *inputExtent = [CIVector vectorWithCGRect:inputImage.extent];
    NSNumber *inputCount = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:256];
    NSNumber *inputScale = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:25];


    CIImage *histogramOutputImage = [inputImage imageByApplyingFilter:@"CIAreaHistogram"
                                                  withInputParameters:@{
                                                                        @"inputExtent" : inputExtent,
                                                                        @"inputCount" : inputCount,
                                                                        @"inputScale" : inputScale}
                                     ];

    CIImage *outHistogramImage = [histogramOutputImage imageByApplyingFilter:@"CIHistogramDisplayFilter"
                                   withInputParameters:nil];

    return outHistogramImage;
}
```

Here is the image to be filtered:

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWPPe.jpg)

And here is my generated Histogram image:

[Histogram from my function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IxZE.png)

Viewing the image in Mac Preview app or Photos app should show the correct histogram with the majority of the colors in the center of the histogram.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling Color Management fixed the issue:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{(id)kCIImageColorSpace : (id)kCFNull};
CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage: image options:options];
```